# How to animate element width on window resize?

Tags: jquery, window-resize

Not sure if I am doing this right but the jq animation is kinda stalling and it is  changing depending if you hold the mouse(LC) on resize resulting in weird effect each time 
http://jsfiddle.net/yMcXm/15/

Desired effect is smoothly resize the box if window size is less than 680px and resize back to 20% if more than 680

I might be using wrong function not sure.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Make your layout fluid with CSS3 media queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below,

```
var timer = null;
$(window).resize(function() {
    var getWidth = $(window).width();

    if (timer != null) clearTimeout(timer);

    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        alert(getWidth);
        if (getWidth < 680) {
            $(".box").animate({
                width: "49%"
            }, 1000);
        } else if (getWidth > 680) {

            $(".box").animate({
                width: "20%"
            }, 1000);
        }
    }, 500);

});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/yMcXm/16/

Comment: thnx for the try but it still kinda shows latency,especially if I don't let go left click. trying to use this instead @media query ,mixing it up with jq masonry